# Drools : Tool for generating .drl files or XML based rule content

Tags: drools, rule-engine

We are using Drools Rule Engine for our Java web Application .

Writing of DRL files seems error Prone. I just wanted to know if there is any tool that automatically generates `.drl` files or either xml based rules?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

You can check the Drools Guvnor project http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-guvnor.html that allows you to create rules via a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a spreadsheet (xls-file) based decision table. This is convenient to use.

You can read more about it here: http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch06.html

Alternatively, you can also create rules from java code, using the "Fluent API", read here:

http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/droolsjbpm-introduction-docs/html/ch02.html#d0e124

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't know any tool that does so, but it really help to install the plugins for your ide.

For example, if you're running eclipse, there is a whole suite that can syntax-check your rule files and automatically report static type checking errors when writing rules.

See [the documentation here...](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/droolsjbpm-introduction-docs/html/ch03.html)

Since there is no real hard bound between the rule files and you classes at "pre-compile" time, this helps a lot.